# insert featured image from one post type to another

Tags: wordpress, post, custom-post-type

I have an 'events' post type with a featured image and I want it so that every time an event post is saved it will create a blog post at the same time using the title, content, author, and featured image. I have it working to the point where it creates the blog post and adds all the fields except for the featured image since there was no featured image field with the wp_insert_post() function. How can I get the featured image from the events post type which is a custom post type and add it to the regular blog post type?

Answer (score 3):

I have the function fully working now and thought I'd share it here in case anyone else is trying to do the same thing and would like to see the code in it's entirety.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'create_event_post' );

function create_event_post( $post_id ) {

    // Set the title, thumbnail id, author, and content variables
    $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    $post_content = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);
    $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
    $author_id = get_post_field ('post_author', $post_id);

    // If the post is not "tribe_events", don't create a new post.  
    if ( "tribe_events" != $post_type ) 
        return;

    $new_post = array(
                'comment_status'    =>  'closed',
                'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
                'post_author'       =>  $author_id,
                'post_title'        =>  $post_title,
                'post_content'      =>  $post_content,
                'post_status'       =>  'publish',
                'post_type'     =>  'post'
            );

    remove_action( 'save_post', 'create_event_post' );

    $post_exists = get_page_by_title( $post_title, $output, "post" );

    if ( !empty($post_exists) ) {
        // Update post
        $update_post = array(
            'ID'           =>   $post_exists->ID,
            'post_title'   =>   $post_title,
            'post_content' =>   $post_content,
        );

        // Update the post into the database
        wp_update_post( $update_post );
        set_post_thumbnail( $post_exists->ID, $thumbnail_id );
    }
    else {
        // Create the new post and retrieve the id of the new post
        $new_post_id = wp_insert_post ( $new_post );
        // Set the featured image for the new post to the same image as event post 
        set_post_thumbnail( $new_post_id, $thumbnail_id );
    }           

    // Now hook the action
    add_action( 'save_post', 'create_event_post' );
}
```

Thanks to those that answered and hope this can help others in the future!

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress the function to set the featured image is called `set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $thumbnail_id)`.

You can read more about it [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail)

Basically, you could just get the id of the featured image of your 'events' post type, and then pass that id to the `set_post_thumbnail` method after the post has been created with `wp_insert_post()`.

Answer (score 0):

So once you create custom post type. Get the postId of that custom post type.

Then get the thumbnail id of that event post by `get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );` 
ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id

Then once you created the blog post get the postId of the blog post then assign the thumbnail id to that post `set_post_thumbnail( $post, $thumbnail_id );` 
ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail

Should work for what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've added `$thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
 set_post_thumbnail( $post, $thumbnail_id );` after my wp_insert_post() but it's not adding the image to the newly created post. what am I missing?